# how to Check datetime entered

Tags: c#

I have a textBox where the user enters a datetime using a calendar, I am checking for whether the text box is empty or not by

```
       if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_SendAt.Text) == false)
```

How can I check whether the datetime entered is less or = to the current datetime

Comment: You say "using a calendar" - what exactly do you mean? Do you have access to the calendar control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_SendAt.Text) == false 
             && DateTime.Parse(txt_SendAt.Text) <= DateTime.Now )
```

Comment: Which will throw an exception if `txt_SendAt.Text` is _not_ a DateTime.

Comment: @Oded OP says it comes from a calendar control; I assumed it's always going to be a valid datetime string.

Comment: @Bala R : for instance Infragistics WPF calendar control allows enter wrong date time values

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. error, what should I do bala

Comment: @Mano : you should handle such case by using DateTime.TryParse() as shown in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime enteredDateTime;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txt_SendAt.Text, out enteredDateTime))
{
   Debug.WriteLine("User entered date time in wrong format");
}else
{
   if(enteredDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
   {
      // less or equal
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) or [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) static methods of the `DateTime` class to convert the string to a `DateTime` and compare it to the current DateTime.

```
DateTime input;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txt_SendAt.Text, 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                     DateTimeStyles.None, 
                     out input))
{
  if(input <= DateTime.Now)
  {
    // your code here
  }
}
else
{
 //not a valid DateTime string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Parse` or `TryParse` the text to `DateTime`, then compare to `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 0):

A few steps here, first check *something* is entered, as you have done, secondly, check it is actually a date, and lastly check against the desired date, as such:

```
var input = DateTextBox.Text;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out date))
    {
        if (date <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            //bingo!
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `TryParse` for checking proper formatting of the input string as a date - using only `Parse` is a sure way to make your app go *BANG!*

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your string input to a `DateTime` using the [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method, then run your comparison in the normal way.

Remember, `Parse` methods will throw a `FormatException` if the input is not directly castable to the required type. It may make more sense to go for the TryParse method if you have, for example, a free-text input.

```
var inputDate = DateTime.Parse(txt_SendAt.Text);
if (inputDate > DateTime.Now)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime entered is after now.");
}
else if (inputDate < DateTime.Now)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime entered is before now.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_SendAt.Text) && Datetime.Parse(txt_SendAt.Text)<=Datetime.Now)
{
   /*code */
}
else
{
   /*code */
}
```